# Pandas: how to create a year-week variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with datetimes

```
dates = pd.date_range('9/25/2010', periods=10, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':dates})
df['col']=pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
df['dow'] = df.col.dt.dayofweek
df['week'] = df.col.dt.to_period('W')
df['week_alt']=df.col.dt.year.astype(str) + '-w' + df.col.dt.week.astype(str)

df
Out[21]: 
         col  dow                  week  week_alt
0 2010-09-25    5 2010-09-20/2010-09-26  2010-w38
1 2010-09-26    6 2010-09-20/2010-09-26  2010-w38
2 2010-09-27    0 2010-09-27/2010-10-03  2010-w39
3 2010-09-28    1 2010-09-27/2010-10-03  2010-w39
4 2010-09-29    2 2010-09-27/2010-10-03  2010-w39
5 2010-09-30    3 2010-09-27/2010-10-03  2010-w39
6 2010-10-01    4 2010-09-27/2010-10-03  2010-w39
7 2010-10-02    5 2010-09-27/2010-10-03  2010-w39
8 2010-10-03    6 2010-09-27/2010-10-03  2010-w39
9 2010-10-04    0 2010-10-04/2010-10-10  2010-w40
```

Here you can see that a week starts on `Monday` and ends on `Sunday`.

I would like to have control over when a week starts. For instance, if weeks now start on Sunday instead, then  `2010-09-26` would be `2010-w39` and `2010-10-03` be `2010-w40`.

How can I do that in Pandas?

Comment: I use the module [isoweek](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isoweek/1.3.0) but you can't control the day the week starts.

Comment: As it is it is wrong. 

Appending week to year usually gives a wrong answer on the first days of the new year: 1st January will have the new year number but the last year last week. 
i.e. 1/1/2017 will be returned as 2017-w52.

Comment: @AlexPoca If what you say is true, then it is the `df.col.dt.week` field's failure and not the logic's.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE:** you can choose between these three UNIX modifiers: `%U`,`%V`,`%W`:

> **%U**    week number of year, with Sunday as first day of week (00..53).
>
> **%V**    ISO week number, with Monday as first day of week (01..53).
>
> **%W**    week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (00..53).

```
In [189]: df.col.dt.strftime('%U-%V-%W')
Out[189]:
0    38-38-38
1    39-38-38
2    39-39-39
3    39-39-39
4    39-39-39
5    39-39-39
6    39-39-39
7    39-39-39
8    40-39-39
9    40-40-40
Name: col, dtype: object
```

`%U` week number of year, with Sunday as first day of week (00..53).

```
In [190]: df.col.dt.strftime('%Y-w%U')
Out[190]:
0    2010-w38
1    2010-w39
2    2010-w39
3    2010-w39
4    2010-w39
5    2010-w39
6    2010-w39
7    2010-w39
8    2010-w40
9    2010-w40
Name: col, dtype: object
```

`%V`    ISO week number, with Monday as first day of week (01..53).

```
In [191]: df.col.dt.strftime('%Y-w%V')
Out[191]:
0    2010-w38
1    2010-w38
2    2010-w39
3    2010-w39
4    2010-w39
5    2010-w39
6    2010-w39
7    2010-w39
8    2010-w39
9    2010-w40
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: very nice, but how can I control the definition of a week? That is, definining which day of the week is the first day of the week ;-) Say sunday or Monday for instance

Comment: @Noobie, do you need a `weekofyear` or a `weekday`?

Comment: I need to define which day is the first day of any given week. Say, a week starts on Sunday and ends on the next Saturday. I want to be able to use that variable for grouping and for plotting (does Pandas understands that this is a time variable?)

Comment: @Noobie, could you provide an example where pandas would give you a wrong `week#` and what would you like to have instead?

Comment: Adding week to year usually returns wrong conversions on the first days of the year: 1/1/2017 is returned as 2017-w52, that's obviously wrong.

Comment: @AlexPoca, it's not wrong. It follows [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: According the wiki you pointed to, under "Week Dates", you read: 

** Sunday 3 January 2010 is written "2009-W53-7" **

Using the initial algorithm we get "2010" for the year, and "53" for the proper week, and this returns "2010-w53", not the correct "2009-w53".

Comment: @AlexPoca, i got youe point now, thank you! Yes, you are right. I have removed the "old answer"...

Comment: Yes, it is the algorithm that's wrong. Appending week to year doesn't look safe. I will go through it to find a proper solution because I am working on the same issue.

Comment: @AlexPoca, but `df.col.dt.strftime('%Y-w%V')` or `df.col.dt.strftime('%Y-w%U')` - should work properly...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152496/discussion-between-alex-poca-and-maxu).

Comment: This is not ISO definition, e.g. 1st of Jan would be wrong most of the years.