# How to convert date to week number that follow the year?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(df['Created'])
Created=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Created'])
df['CreatedDate']=Created.date
df['CreatedTime']=Created.time
df['CreatedDate']=pd.to_datetime(df['CreatedDate'], errors='coerce')
df['CreatedWW']=df['CreatedDate'].dt.week
```

Output:
[image]

I wish to get output which is for example:

```
CreatedWW
201715
201713
201713
.
.
201646
```

Anyone can share me idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: how to create a year-week variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208305/pandas-how-to-create-a-year-week-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `format` and then [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

All formats for both functions are in http://strftime.org/

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Created':['12/Apr/17 1:21 PM','27/Mar/17 11:06 AM']})
print (df)
              Created
0   12/Apr/17 1:21 PM
1  27/Mar/17 11:06 AM

df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created'], format='%d/%b/%y %H:%M %p').dt.strftime('%Y%V')
print (df)
              Created     new
0   12/Apr/17 1:21 PM  201715
1  27/Mar/17 11:06 AM  201713
```